# Как установить драйвер php5-mongo нужной версии на Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

Когда смотрю подробнее о модуле следующей командой

```
apt-cache show php5-mongo
```

Выводится информация, что версия 1.4.5built1 модуля php5-mongo и находится он в репозитории `Filename: pool/universe/p/php-mongo/php5-mongo_1.4.5-1build1_amd64.deb`

Установить я его могу следующей командой

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

Но мне нужна версия 1.6, так как она поддерживает Mongo 3.0

Как мне 1-2-3 командами установить версию 1.6 драйвера php5-mongo?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Во первых выше указанной командой вы всего лишь устанавливаете консольную версию php5.

Во вторых драйвер монго лучше ставить из pecl.

**Обновление**

```
apt-get install pecl. pecl search mongo
```

Comment: Исправил. А как из пекл?